# Using a Variable in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a single query that returns a result if the id is found in either Result1 or Result2, but also searches for that ID in another table to return the 'skill.'

The query is in a loop so the ID changes. How can I change the query below to utilize the variable ID to match something in a given table column?

```
query = "SELECT "
        "a.Item1, a.Item2, a.Result1, a.Result2, b.skill "
        "FROM formulas AS a "
        "LEFT JOIN skills AS b "
        "USING (%u AS Id) "
        "WHERE Type != 0 AND Result1 = %u OR Result2 = %u;";
```

Area of concern is: USING (%u AS Id)

(Edit: Cleaned up code for readability)

Comment: Personally I've not seen an alias in a using clause; and I generally avoid them and go with being explicit using `On` On what field(s) do formula's and skills relate?  what is the PK/FK relationship?   2nd.  From what table is Type?  hopefully not skills!

Comment: Posted my own answer, sorry! I just had a 'brain lapse' for a second... Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out...I just used 'ON'...

```
query = "SELECT "
        "a.Item1, a.Item2, a.Result1, a.Result2, b.skill "
        "FROM formulas AS a "
        "LEFT JOIN skills AS b "
        "ON (Id = %u) "
        "WHERE Type != 0 AND Result1 = %u OR Result2 = %u;";
```

Comment: Yep; using requires the columns in both tables to be named the same and of the same type; on gives you more flexibility. I prefer the fully qualified method s